# emgu.cv framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App'

Tags: emgucv

Hi All,

I deploy emgu.cv on CentOS 7, I got  The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' was not found ..

below what I have:

[root@demo Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]# dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.3 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

I am not using Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App in my ASP Net Core project..

Comment: which version of emgucv do you use

Comment: I use the latest 4.3.0.3890

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a know issue for .NETCore-Apps on a non Windows-Machine.
Will be fixed with v4.4

https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/339

update:
v4.4 is released and compiles with .NET Standard 2.0 projects on all platforms